# How do I access an iVar from a different .swift file within the same target?

Tags: swift, reloaddata

I want to access an IBOutlet declared in my ViewController.swift from 
my ImageDownloader.swift file; i.e., (ImageDownloader.swift --> ViewController.swift).

But the compiler can't find it.

[image]

Note: the target object is a member of a class (ViewController) and hence, isn't global.

**ViewController.swift:** {Calling Target}

[image]

**ImageDownloader.swift:** {Calling Source}

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
    if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
       if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
           self.image = UIImage(data:data)

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                viewcontroller.collectionView.reloadData()  // ...compiler error.
           })

        }
    }
}
```

Compiler Error:

> ...Use of unresolved identifier 'collectionView'

[image]
How do I reference an IBOutlet var in a different .swift file?

---

Here's the Obj-C version of what I'm trying to do:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

...where rather than referencing collectionView from within the SAME swift file, I reference form another swift file.

...perhaps this is a poor paradigm to follow; to use closures instead, per feedback.

Comment: The error message is very clear: you should have something like `viewcontroller.collectionView.reloadData()` in the closure

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.  Hence revised query.

Comment: How did u declare the variable viewcontroller? Please add this to your question

Comment: Done. See revised query.

Comment: Per @Athony's comment, you have to actually have a variable, unless you're still missing some code in your posting.  Can you show where you declare the (poorly named) "viewController" property in your calling class?  Since collectionView is not a class variable (and they aren't supported yet anyway), it is not yet evident how / where you are storing it.  And this has nothing to do with IBOutlet, just scoping.

Comment: The 'collectionView' is merely an IBOutlet var that I want access to from a different .swift (vs same file in Obj-C) so I can force reloadData.  I've added clarification via Objective-C equivalent.  But perhaps I should use the delegation + closure paradigm for Swift... ...Neophyte trying to formulate the best pattern/paradigm for this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your local `viewcontroller` variable. I assume this is actually a property (referring to it as `self.viewcontroller` would help reduce confusion). I suspect you have a typo there. Maybe you meant `self.viewController` for instance.

That said, you should not try to access another view controller's IBOutlets directly. IBOutlets are implementation details of a view controller. They are subject to change any time you modify your UI.

Ideally, the view controller should be a delegate of whatever object this is, or should have passed a closure to this object, so that the view controller is able to manage reloading its own collection view.

As a second best approach, your view controller should have a method, such as `refresh()` that you can call to do whatever UI is required when the data has changed. That way this object does not need internal details about the view controller.

Comment: I've added clarification.  But I've noticed your suggestion of using the delegation paradigm with closure.  ...I'll study this.

Comment: BTW: Recognized your name.  Bought your iOS 6 book.  I'll DEFINITELY follow/study your 'ideal' solution here.